# I don't have a Glass BSDF

Tags: node-editor, glass

I am new to blender and am trying to make a gemstone. I already have it modeled and am on to texturing but the tutorial I found uses a glass bsdf but I don't have one in my add node selection. I tried googleing it but all I found were more tutorials. Do I need to turn something on or download it?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It should be there by default with all the other shader nodes. What version of blender are you using? Also, are you using Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: I am running 2.83 and EEVEE but I might be doing everything wrong since the tutorial jumps right from modeling to texturing without any info on setting it up.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the area where the node should be?

Comment: https://imgur.com/ERzmPHd it wont let me post an image here. If I understand correctly it should be here somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the wrong editor window (texture editor)

[image]

Use the **Shader** editor.

[image]